# Webpack Encore - Get versionned files in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I installed Symfony 4 with Webpack Encore recently. 
I use some static assets to make a PDF with TCPDF.
To do that, I used to get images with their path but with Webpack Encore versionning, filenames are different so I can't get images this way.
Is there a solution to keep versionning and access these images in PHP ?

PHP :

```
$logourl = trim("../public/build/images/tst_noir.png");
$pdf->Image($logourl, 135, 10.8, 42, 0);
```

Webpack app.js :

```
require('../images/tst_noir.png');
```

Webpack-config.js :

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
.setPublicPath('http://localhost/xxx/public/build')
.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
.autoProvidejQuery()
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js');

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Symfony configuration for the assets setup for the use on a website, you can use the [assets.packages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html#asset-packages) package to fetch the final display-ready URLs for a file:

```
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Package;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\EmptyVersionStrategy;

$package = new Package(new EmptyVersionStrategy());

// Absolute path
echo $package->getUrl('/image.png');
// result: /image.png

// Relative path
echo $package->getUrl('image.png');
// result: image.png
```

Versioning and URL prefixes should also be handled if the Symfony & [Webpack](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/cdn.html) configuration (or setting up the component directly) has been put in place.

```
// webpack.config.js
if (Encore.isProduction()) {
    Encore.setPublicPath('https://my-cool-app.com.global.prod.fastly.net');
    Encore.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/');
}
```

Before Symfony 3.0, `templating.helper.assets` provided much the same functionality, but now you are more likely to use the `framework.assets.json_manifest_path:` config.